# How do I make an xpath with a variable for a selenide test

Tags: java, selenium, string-formatting, ui-testing, selenide

I want to write a testmethod which I can give a parameter which will define which element to test.

Something like;

```
public void addImage(String imageNr){
     $(By.xpath("(//input[@name='image'])['" + imageNr + "']"));
}
```

To get i.e. `(//input[@name='image'])[2] or (//input[@name='image'])[3]`

How would I go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

within Selenide you have something called the ElementsCollection. More information can be found on this page: https://selenide.gitbooks.io/user-guide/content/en/selenide-api/elements-collection.html

What you can do is transform the SelenideElement to an ElementsCollection by using double dollar signs:

For example:

- This .get requires an Integer type. It will give you first all elements and you can take the second element from the returned list.

$$(By.xpath("(//input[@name='image'])).get(pageNr)

You will still need to do an action after getting this. for Example .click();

Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the XPath String expression with the use of `String.format`, as following:

```java
public void addImage(String imageNr){
    String xpath = "(//input[@name='image'])[{0}]";
    xpath = String.format(xpath,imageNr);
     $(By.xpath(xpath));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer regrettably that does not work it seems. 
the IDE seems to interpret the 1st semicolon as a string, the second one not. I get "Expression expected" and "unexpected end of file"... 
I tried with a "%s" etc... I can't seem to find anything online either.